# find a pattern in string and remove that pattern of the string from excel cells without touching the pattern in the middle of the string

Tags: regex, string, excel, replace, excel-formula

I have a column which has "--" pattern in the beginning, middle and end of the string. For example:

```
-- myString
my -- String
myString --
```

I want to find these two types of cells

```
-- myString
myString --
```

and remove the "--" pattern, so it will look fine! I am an amateur user of excel but can use functions if you suggest me. It should be possible with find and use the results of the Find in Replace functions, but I do not know how to pass the results to Replace.

Please note: The answer should take care all the cells in the column, which are hundreds. One solution for changing all, not one solution for one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer. The answer from @Dubison helped me to find the right answer. 
 If the left two characters in this cell is "--" and the last two characters are "--" the substitute the "--" with "", else to nothing.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="--",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--",""),IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="--",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--",""), A1))
```

Comment: hi, I am glad you found your answer. I misread your question. I thought you only want to remove "--" which are in the middle. Sorry for that. At least you have found the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Just reread the request, per instruction from Gary'sStudent. This will remove all instances of "--", not only those at the beginning/end.

If the data is in A1, use the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","")
```

Comment: Your formula will remove **internal --**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent what do you mean it will remove internal? EDIT: I just reread the request. He only wants to remove those at the beginning and end. You are correct!

Comment: Here's another option, just because I messed up on my first try: `=MID(A1,(LEFT(A1,2) = "--")*2+1,LEN(A1)-(RIGHT(A1,2)="--")*2)`

Comment: I put a note in the end of the question. The answers should take care of all the cells (in one column) that contains the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="--",MID(A1,3,9999),IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="--",MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-2),A1))
```

Comment: Doesn't make a change!

Answer (score 0):

This will be pretty much the same with previous answers, only using simpler logic. If your strings first or last character = "-" do nothing, else replace "--" with "".

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="-",A1,IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="-",A1, SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","")))
```

UPDATE:

I noticed that I have misread the question. Above code will remove the "--" only if it is in the middle. However original question was to remove "--" only if it is at the beginning or at the end. So formula should be:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,2)="--",RIGHT(A1,2)="--"),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--",""),A1)
```

Comment: It removes the middle ones. You are closer than others as it removes the end and beginning! Could you please check your answer

Comment: Those two first IFs do not do any help and what is working is =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","") which replaces all the "--" with "" including the -- in the middle!